# UITableViewCell doesn't change background color of first cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I'm trying to change the background color of all the cells in a UITableView to clear color, but I can't change the first cell.  The first cell remains white.  There are no other views in my storyboard that are causing this.

I tried this and it still didn't work

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
}
```

I can email you the code if you'd like to see the problem for yourself.  Once you have the code, just run simulate and hit the "Run Client" button that I made.

Comment: Are you sure that this is in the tableview delegate?

Comment: Why not move this code to cellForRowAtIndexPath ? it should work there

Comment: Yeah if you can toss the code online that would make it easier to hel find a fix.